MySQL STR_TO_DATE avoid 2digit year ambiguity
I want to test strictly if date strings are stored in a given format in a MYSQL table.
The format I want to check is:
DD/MM/YYYY
The important part for me is four year digits.
At first it looks easy:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21/02/2024', '%d/%m/%Y') # will return 2024-02-21 which is expected
But when the 2year digit ambiguity comes into play MYSQL converts automatically to 4year digit and doesn't report NULL here, even if the format for the year is upper case %Y:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21/02/24', '%d/%m/%Y') # will still return 2024-02-21 when I expect to return NULL
From the documentation:
%Y | Year, numeric, four digits
%y | Year, numeric (two digits)

Why, if the format part of the year with upper case 'Y' telling MYSQL to expect four year digit like stated in the documentation, still resolves the ambiguity automatically and accept as valid year?.
I would like to be able to be strict with the STR_TO_DATE format so that string dates with two digit years are returning NULL like it does with:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21/02/foo', '%d/%m/%Y')
Edit: by ambiguity I mean MySQL converts automatically 2digit years from 00-69 to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999 dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/two-digit-years.html

'You should also be aware that,..checks (only) the individual year...More precisely, this means that the year is checked to be sure that it is in the range 0-9999 inclusive' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date - You need to write your own test.

what do you mean by 2year digit ambiguity?

by ambituity I mean MySQL converts automatically 2digit years from 00-69 to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/two-digit-years.html Since I specifically use uppercase Y in the format, I expect STR_TO_DATE not to convert 2 digit years into guessed 4 digit years

y2k all over again..str_to_date can't help you here ,you need to identify (and fix?) using string functions.

I understand by your response that it is expected to pass a format explicitly telling to use 4 digit year and yet the STR TO DATE function auto convert 2 digit to four digit guessing century, and I have to custom circumvent the expected behaviour with additional functions?

Why not just use a regular expression? Test if the date matches^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$'

I think I will have to do a combination of both, regex for the number of digits in Year and str_to_date to check if date exists ( ie returning NULL if 31 of April... )

Wouldn't it be better to validate when the data is entered?

@Barnar Yes of course it would be better to validate on data being entered, but that's not the point. In this case I have data already set which I have to validate quality and in this particular case I test dates expecting four digit YEAR.
